# Change mouse pointer in iTerm2 (or disable mouse pointer)

Tags: mouse, iterm

In iTerm2 (fullscreen mode) my pointer is permanently a "text select" pointer. It bothers me, so I would either like to change it (to the regular arrow-type pointer) or disable it when in my fullscreen iTerm2 instance. Is this possible? I'm on OSX 10.7.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite old, but...

Open finder (or mc or anything else) then go to /Applications/Iterm.app (press right mouse and choose "Show package content" if in Finder) Content/Resource/

IBarCursor.tiff and IBarCursorXMR.tiff are the cursor images. You can replace or delete them.

Comment: Note that depending on the user's version of OS X/macOS and the way the application is designed and published, modifying the contents of the .app package may render it unable to run as it will no longer be a signed bundle.

Comment: Not the case. Replace safely.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the authentication for apps is something stored in PRAM or NVRAM and only checked the first time it's opened. I only say that because resetting those seems to trigger all of those warnings again.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is inconsistent between window mode and full screen mode, but this is not something that is configurable. You would probably have to submit a feature request to get this changed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this wouldn't be possible using iTerm configs. Alternatively, is there a way I can just disable the pointer when in iTerm?